# EditText now showing under ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@android:id/list" />
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/search" android:hint="Filter results" />
```

What is causing my `ListView` to cover up my edit text?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps try doing:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@android:id/list"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:hint="Filter results"/>
```

That way your `ListView` will grow to fill only *unused* space regardless of its own content requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the weight =1  and height 0dp in Listview :
As fill_parent is deprecated so use match_parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Filter results" />
</LinearLayout>
```