# A ListView under a WebView

Tags: android, listview, layout, webview, forum

I am writing an Android app to display a forum.
The content of the main article is in a `WebView`, and I'd like to put the answers into a `ListView` under the main article.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        //android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:textColor="#FFDEC2" />

    <ListView

        android:id="@+id/contentlist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here the `ListView` isn't displayed at all. If I enable

```
android:layout_weight="1.0"
```

the screen gets split, both are shown, but the `ListView` should be under the `WebView`, so that there is just one scrollbar for both.

I think this article: [Android layout - listview and edittext below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069594/android-layout-listview-and-edittext-below) is about my problem, but I don't understand how to edit the code of this [site](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) to fit to my problem.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You can't have a listview in a scroll view or visa versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raybritton is correct. You cannot have a ListView and a Web view share the same scrollbar. You cant nest scrollviews.

What it sounds like you will need to do is create a ListView adapter. This way you can create a custom view for each row of the list.

Follow this example: 
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Then place a WebView inside the layout and set its visibility to "Gone". When you are ready to have it appear set it to "Visible" in the code. State that the ListView only has 2 rows. Both rows will share the same layout, but this is where you specify the individual visibility of each item to make the rows look different.

**So long story short:** become familiar with ListView adapters and hiding views.

Hope that makes sense!