# Show the Entire ListView in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout

I try to place a `ListView` under a `WebView`, to do this I use the folloing xml code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:textColor="#FFDEC2" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/comments"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The code displays the content of the `WebView` and `ListView` correctly, but the `ListView` just has the high of about 1.5 times the `ListView` Item, so not the entire List is displayed but just the first  Items.

I tried several combinations of `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in the `LinearLayout`, `WebView`, `ListView` and the surrounding `ScrollView`, none of them worked.

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer to your question but one observation...putting scrollable UI elements into a `ScrollView` really isn't a good idea and can result in unpredictable behaviour. Both `WebView` and `ListView` are (or can be) scrollable.

Comment: I know that this solution isnt nice at all, but in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152071/a-listview-under-a-webview) question i asked for an other way, but i'm happy that i found  anything at all.

Comment: What is the source of the list? Is it variable or do you have a fixed number of items you want to display? If it's fixed, how many items are there?

Comment: i am testing it with a string array but if it works i will replace it with a arraylist, which contains the comments of a forum article, so the number is different every time.

Comment: But if it's variable then you're never going to see all the items in one go - that's the point of a `ListView` being scrollable - the adapter can reference 100s or 1000s of items and the `ListView` will show a small (finite) number at any one time but allowing the user to scroll through the total number. If you want all of the items to appear below the `WebView` (within a `ScrollView`) then try dynamically creating and adding item views to the `ScrollView`, e.g., one `TextView` per item. I still think having a `WebView` in a `ScrollView` is a bad idea though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use layout weights. It's a way to use percentages to define your layout.

In the following example, the ListView uses 60% of the space, and the WebView 40% :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:textColor="#FFDEC2"
        android:layout_weight=".40" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/comments"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".60" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Just change these percentages to whatever you want.

Comment: this isn't working, I tried several values, but I think weight isn't working in a ScrollView.

Comment: You can try to set fix heights to your two views. I don't think there's an other way if you want to use a ScrollView. For example you can do it programmatically by getting the height of the screen, and set this as the height for each view.

Comment: But I think you should follow MisterSquonk's advice and forgot this layout. IMO you will have another problem after this one, even if you get what you want...

Comment: I already had a solution, where the upper part of the display is the WebView and the lower part the List, but I want to Display a WebView and at the end of the WebView the List. Both should work with one scrollbar.